# Highcharts Gauge not appearing

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have got the charts working before, however now they don't want to appear. I am trying to use the Gauge.

This is what's in the header:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

This is the PHP:

```
echo "<div id='graph_one' style='width:30%; height:200px; float:left;'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>

 $(function () {

$('#graph_one').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]        
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}, 
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
    });
});

</script>";
```

Comment: Why do you echo your html/js?? And maybe, if it not too much effort for you, you should add some information about errors etc. "Does not appear" is not really helpful

Comment: It's a javascript error - how could I display that ?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have developer toolbars with a lot of information available. There you have a JS console showing all error information

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I open your example in your form, and all works properly, but do you use any webserver? Because php files cannot be opened without that.

Comment: I'm using it live on a host... I'm perplexed as to why it's not functioning - because I got it working before on the same host- the same way.. .

Comment: Have you any live demo, on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Give the reference of javascript locally. Sometimes it happens that the reference is not being taken directly from the web. Save the `jquery.min.js` `highcharts.js` `highcharts-more.js` and `exporting.js` locally in your system and give the path to the stored file.